# Chrome extension WebNavigation API getFrame

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I found a chrome extension WebNavigation API, but I don't know how to use it. Could someone give me a simple example?

API:

```
chrome.webNavigation.getFrame(object details, function callback)
```

If I want to get iframe id and iframe's scr in a page, can I use this API ??

Answer (score 3):

As the [docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#method-getFrame) state, one needs to pass tabId, processId, frameId...

in order to get these values, one needs to listen for .onCompleted():

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(e){

    chrome.webNavigation.getFrame(
        {tabId: e.tabId, processId: e.processId, frameId: e.frameId},
        function(details){
            console.dir(details);
        }
    );

});
```

The event's properties are already known before the .getFrame()

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access page content you should use [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html)

So, for example in the manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.example.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
}
```

And in myscript.js:

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
alert(iframe.getAttribute('id'), iframe.getAttribute('src'));
```

Another way is to use [programmatic injection](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi) which is in fact simplified content scripting.

Update:
To get src from all iframes on the page:

```
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
for(var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++){
    console.log(iframes[i].getAttribute('id'), iframes[i].getAttribute('src'));
}
```

Comment: Excuse me , I'm try this code,I can get some iframe src but I can't get all the iframe src in the page,please help me. Thanks for help.

Comment: You should just iterate thru dom objects - I have added a special update ;)

Comment: This technique is extremely limited. The src  attribute of an iframe reflects only the original URL loaded into it. If the user navigates the iframe by clicking a link in the iframed page, the src attribute won't change.